# Objective-C: extending UIViewController leads to unexpected sense of "self" and "super"

Tags: java, ios, uiviewcontroller

Let's say I have a UIViewController

```
@interface CustomController : UIViewController 
@end

@implementation CustomController

- (void)myMethod {
     //this is the problematic line. It calls viewDidLoad of ExtendedController
     //but it should be calling viewDidLoad of CustomController
     [self viewDidLoad]; 
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   //and this line should call viewDidLoad from UIViewController
   [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

And then I have another which extends that one

```
@interface ExtendedController : CustomController
@end

@implementation ExtendedController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super myMethod];
}
```

When ExtendedController is launched, it calls the viewDidLoad in ExtendedController, which then calls myMethod of CustomController, which then calls viewDidLoad of ExtendedController, and it's an infinite loop.

How can I make it so CustomController's myMethod always calls viewDidLoad in CustomController class, not any other class.

This doesn't make much sense to me, because in Java, for instance, this set up works as expected. But somehow, the notion of "self" is lost when extending classes in iOS.

```
public class Hello extends Omg {
   public void myMethod() {
      //in Java, this method does indeed call "viewDidLoad" in "Hello"
      this.viewDidLoad();
   }

   public viewDidLoad() {
      //in Java, this method does indeed call "viewDidLoad" in class "Omg"
      super.viewDidLoad(); 
   }
}

public class ExtendedHello {
   public void viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad();
   }
}
```

How can I fix my iOS code to get the expected behavior?

UPDATE: note that "viewDidLoad" can be replaced by any method name...This question has nothing to do with the fact that it is viewDidLoad.

Thanks!

Comment: Just in case you did not know; you should never ever call viewDidLoad manually but let the system do it when needed. To trigger a viewController's view getting loaded all you need is to reference that view (commonly from outside of that class itself).

Comment: Why are you calling viewDidLoad in the first place? That's done by the system.

Comment: Okay well regardless of the method name....I just picked any random method name.

Comment: If you want to call an instance method of the superclass, then you need to get an instance somehow (by creating it or referencing one already created) and then call the method on that instance. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: I see some objective-c runtime hacking answers coming .... :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly how it's supposed to work in Objective C. When you call [self viewDidLoad], it's actually generating a call to objc_msgSend(self,@selector(viewDidLoad),...), which uses 'self' (which in this case happens to be an instance of ExtendedController) to look up the actual function to execute. In short 'self' is an instance of the actual class, so if a superclass defines that function, that's the one that will be called.

As an aside, it probably doesn't make sense for you to be calling viewDidLoad, since that's called automatically at a specific time.

Comment: Interesting. So, how can I achieve the behavior I want? And note that viewDidLoad can be replaced with any other method.